# Pandoc not maintaining newlines from .txt file to Word file

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am using Pandoc to integrate Scrivener with Zotero. I write in Scrivener adding the Zotero citation keys, compile a .txt file, then use Pandoc to convert the .txt file into a Word file in which the citation keys are effectively translated in my preferred citation style (APA in this case). Following the instructions on [this](https://davepwsmith.github.io/academic-scrivener-howto/) webpage, I also set up "Marked 2" to show the output of what I was writing in Scrivener using markdown.

Here comes the problem: newlines.
If I write in Scrivener:

```
I want a newline after this.
This should be a newline.
```

then Marked 2 is showing:

```
I want a newline after this. This should be a newline.
```

So then I wrote in Scrivener:

```
I want a newline after this.<br>
This should be a newline.
```

Marked 2:

```
I want a newline after this.
This should be a newline.
```

Great! Now I compile into a .txt file and I get:

```
I want a newline after this.<br>
This should be a newline.
```

OK, now it is time to use Pandoc.

I type the following command into the terminal:

```
pandoc -s -S --normalize --bibliography  
~/Dropbox/_Research/Master_Thesis/Master.bib --csl 
~/Dropbox/_Research/apa.csl 
-f markdown -t docx -o trial.docx /Users/S/Desktop/test_st.txt
```

I get my .docx file (and when I do this with a full document, all my citations are there, so that works!), but then I read:

```
I want a newline after this. This should be a newline.
```

Note that the newline command that was present in the .txt file is gone, but still I did not get a newline.

Comment: The primary of source of help with Pandoc is its [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/pandoc-discuss). Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you, actually I found it after posting this questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that the *traditional* way of writing a hard linebreak in markdown is by appending two spaces to the end of the line

```
I want a newline after this.␠␠
This should be a newline.
```

The `<br>` element is interpreted as raw HTML, i.e., it would be rendered in any format which supports HTML, like Markdown or HTML itself. Docx, however, doesn't support raw HTML, so the `<br>` is simply dropped.

So either use the traditional Markdown syntax explained above (which is ugly IMHO), or use a pandoc feature which allows to add hard linebreaks by ending a line with a backslash, "escaping" the newline:

```
I want a newline after this.\
This should be a newline.
```

Comment: Thank you. Another option I found is to add -f markdown+hard_line_breaks to the pandoc command.

Comment: It should be noted that Emy's suggestion "pandoc -f markdown+hard_line_breaks" works fine also on plain text files.